# Concurrency issues with parallel()

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, java-stream, spliterator

I have a problem, where this code does not return the same value each time it is run. I assume it is because it is not threadsafe and I am having some concurrency issues with parallel(). I have tried to use a spliterator, and that works, but runtime because 3 times worse, the same as sequental. How else can I do this ?

Ps:
traverseDirectory returns a BlockingQueue of all .txt files in a directory.

```
try {
    pq = traverseDirectory(dir, pq);

    while(!pq.isEmpty()){

        File f = pq.take();
        LineNumberReader lr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(f));
        lr.lines()
            .parallel()
            .forEach((line) -> {
                String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
                for( String word : words ){
                    wordList.add(word);
                }

             }); // foreach

     } // while

} //try
catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {}

System.out.println("size: " + wordList.size());
```

*EDIT*
I forgot to mention, that I need to keep track of in which line the word has been found!

Answer (score 2):

Lists are not guaranteed to be thread safe, so when you write to your word list, concurrent writes to the list could interfere with each other, especially when the list is modified structurally to accommodate added values. The documentation recommends assuring synchronized access to the list in that situation.

You are better off replacing the `forEach` with more stream processing in order to avoid such concurrency issues.  Instead of the `forEach`, try something like

```
.flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s+")))
```

That will yield a stream of all of the words in all of the lines.  You could then terminate the stream with `.count()` to get the number of words, or `collect()` them to a collection of some kind.

@Holger pointed out that by repeatedly splitting with a `String` regex, the same regex gets re-compiled on every iteration.  By using instead

```
.flatMap(Pattern.compile("\\s+")::splitAsStream)
```

the regex gets compiled only once per file.

Comment: Correct, but you may consider using `.flatMap(Pattern.compile("\\s+")::splitAsStream)` instead. It ensures that the regex pattern is parsed exactly once rather than for each line and it won’t fill an intermediate array for each line.

Comment: @Holger `splitAsStream` is a new one for me. You've made my day.

Comment: @Holger What exactly does flatMap do?

Comment: `splitAsStream` returns a `Stream<String>`, so using it in a `map()` would turn your `Stream<String>` into a `Stream<Stream<String>>`.  Using `flatMap()` takes everything in the inner streams and connects them into one stream, resulting in a `Stream<String>`

Comment: @Hank Thanks for that!
Btw. I need to keep track of in which line the word has been found. This is very important.